# Implementing the ratio of uniforms for normal distribution in C++

Tags: c++, random, normal-distribution

I understand that this can be done by defining a teardrop shape and accepting points that fall within that region (from a uniform generator).

I am trying to do this in C++ by generating two uniform random numbers x and y to locate the point (x,y), and then checking if this point falls within the region.

I don't have a problem with the code itself, but is there a flaw in my logic here? I haven't found a suitable graphical way to check if this is true normal distribution yet.

Here is the code which is supposed to work:

```
typedef unsigned long long int Ullong;
typedef double Doub;

struct Normaldev : Ran {
    Doub mu,sig;

    Normaldev (Doub mmu, Doub ssig, Ullong i)
        : Ran (i), mu(mmu), sig(ssig){}

    Doub dev() {

      Doub u, v, x, y, q;
        do {
          u=Doub();
          v=1.7156*(Doub()-0.5);
          x=u-0.449871;
          y=abs(v)+0.386595;
          q=x*x+y*(0.19600*y-0.25472*x);
        } while(q>0.27597 && (q>0.27846 || v*v>-4*log(u)*u*u));

        return mu+sig*v/u;
     }
};
```

I changed the suggested code in the Numerical Recipes book as much as I could with my rudimentary knowledge of C++, but what exactly is Ran supposed to be?

Comment: Checking if the distribution is normal is done via the Shapiro test. For the RoU method for the normal distribution, there is code and math in Numerical Recipes 3rd edition. Basically, you use bounding ellipses to test quickly whether the point (x, y) is within the region or not.

Comment: I've read the associated page in that book, http://tinyurl.com/9oh2nqg and I am not sure if I'm grasping the theory behind it well. The code is in C?

Comment: The code is (bad) C++. What are you unsure about ? From your original question, it seems to me that you understand the method: whenever (x, y) is a uniform sample of the teardrop region, y/x is normally distributed.

Comment: The way I want to code this is: initiate time seed, roll two random numbers as x and y, and decide whether to reject the pair based on whether they fit the x=cos(t) and y=sin(t)*sin(t/2) teardrop parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed the suggested code in the Numerical Recipes book as much as I could with my rudimentary knowledge of C++, but what exactly is Ran supposed to be?

Ran is a parent class of NormalDev.  Its not defined in the code you gave.  Based on the code it seems to be a pretty generic Random number class that takes an `unsigned long long int` seed in its constructor.

Comment: randd here generates a random number from 0 to 1?

Comment: As mentioned in the post.  Yes.

Comment: Box muller is not better than Ratio of Uniforms in computational terms : it rejects more uniform numbers and uses a log and a square root each time.

Comment: @AlexandreC. you are correct.  I have removed the second half of my post.

Comment: Well I used the Box Muller transform for the distribution, for now. It helped me understand a bit more about normal distribution and about C++, but it gets noticeably slower when a larger number of points is demanded.

Comment: Your code, however it works, is higher performance.  Is it a variation of the Inverse normal cumulative distribution method?

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the 3rd Edition of "Numerical Recipes in C", pages 364-369. You'll find out that Box-Muller returns two normally distributed random variables, namely 'u' and 'v'. So the first time the function is called, you calculate both variables but return just 'u'. The second call of the function does nothing but returning 'v'.

```
double  u, v;
double  sigma = 1.0
double  mean  = 0.0;
int     flag  = 0;

double boxMuller()
{
    if (flag == 1) {
        flag  = 0;
        return v * sigma + mean;
    }
    double help;
    do {
        u = Doub() - 0.5;
        v = Doub() - 0.5;
        help      = u * u + v * v;
    } while (help >= 0.25);
    help = sqrt( log( help * 4.0 ) / help * -2.0 );
    u   *= help;
    v   *= help;
    flag = 1;
    return u * sigma + mean;
}
```

The Ratio-of-Uniforms method in contrast has to calculate a new random variable on every call (not every second).

So i measured the times, and prefer using the Box-Muller code above.

Comment: Speed really depends on your underlying uniform generator. I use ratio of uniforms everyday, and have benchmarked it to be way faster than B-M with a Xor-Shift uniform generator. Also, Box-Muller will have biases when you draw many many normals (say from 10^9 on) since it generates numbers between ~ -6 and 6 (if you use a "standard" uniform generator).

Comment: I think the range restriction from -6 to +6 is because of the squares. Since the ratio of uniforms also contains squares, it should not be less restrictive. The best solution here may be a Ziggurat version.

Comment: Btw, you can improve the method by using e.g. 64 bit unsigned integers in the loop to find 'u' and 'v'. To calculate 'help', you can add the upper halves of two full multiplications (128 bit result).